# How can I solve this DiskID conflict amongst my external disks?

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, windows-firewall

I ran a game I hadn't ran in some time, and it popped up with a firewall rule request.   I thought it was odd as I knew one should have already been present.

I examined the rule and the path to the exe was not correct.  It should have been S:\path\to\exe and instead displayed as E:6\path\to\exe

absurd, i'd never seen anything like it so i changed it manually.  Next startup, it prompted me again and recreated the rule i'd modified, wonky path n all.

So i begun digging.   In event viewer was "Disk 12 has the same disk identifiers as one or more disks connected to the system. Go to Microsoft's support website (http://support.microsoft.com) and search for KB2983588 to resolve the issue."

Turns out disk 12 was the problem drive.  (after more scrolling turns out it was all my external drives)

I checked all the guid's with diskpart and they were all unique.  However upon running `Get-PhysicalDisk | select-object FriendlyName,UniqueIdFormat,SerialNumber,UniqueId` I was presented with the following.

[image]

I can only assume that those UniqueId's are the issue, and are whats effecting the path's being all weird in windows firewall.

Does a means exist to fix this?  Aside from the windows firewall path's becoming undiscernable, I'm concerned about other repercussions.   Elsewhere notes that this will also effect storage spaces functionality.

Answer (score 0):

If each disk has its own disk number, you can change uniqueid.

But I did not test safety.. Sorry, do with your own risk..

Run `powershell` as administrator privilege.

Maximize powershell window to identify whole information.

Run `Get-PhysicalDisk` and you can check Number and Size(last column)

Run `diskpart`

Run `list disk` and check infomation from `Get-PhysicalDisk`

Run `select disk 'number'`

Run `uniqueid disk ID='new_disk_id'`

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> Get-PhysicalDisk

Number FriendlyName                   SerialNumber         MediaType CanPool OperationalStatus HealthStatus Usage
------ ------------                   ------------         --------- ------- ----------------- ------------ -----
1      Samsung SSD 970 EVO Plus 500GB 0025_3853_0140_300B. SSD       False   OK                Healthy      Auto-Select
0      TS512GSSD230S                  E925840739           SSD       False   OK                Healthy      Auto-Select


PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> Get-PhysicalDisk

Number FriendlyName                   SerialNumber         MediaType CanPool OperationalStatus HealthStatus Usage            Size
------ ------------                   ------------         --------- ------- ----------------- ------------ -----            ----
1      Samsung SSD 970 EVO Plus 500GB 0025_3853_0140_300B. SSD       False   OK                Healthy      Auto-Select 465.76 GB
0      TS512GSSD230S                  E925840739           SSD       False   OK                Healthy      Auto-Select 476.94 GB


PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> diskpart

Microsoft DiskPart version 10.0.18362.1

Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.
On computer: LAPTOP-ABCDE1

DISKPART> list disk

  Disk ###  Status         Size     Free     Dyn  Gpt
  --------  -------------  -------  -------  ---  ---
  Disk 0    Online          476 GB      0 B        *
  Disk 1    Online          465 GB  3072 KB        *

DISKPART> select disk 1

Disk 1 is now the selected disk.

DISKPART> uniqueid disk ID=5000000000000002
```

Comment: unfortunately the uniqueid that is changed by running that command is the 32 character gpt guid of which is already unique/different between the disks.

see here for more info

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/3c69bf50-5201-4aa4-95c5-212086906ef7/disk-ltngt-has-the-same-disk-identifiers-as-one-or-more-disks-connected-to-the-system?forum=win10itprohardware

thank you for taking the time for your post though!

Answer (score 0):

DISKPART> uniqueid disk ID=5000000000000002

The specified identifier is not in the correct format.
Type the identifier in the correct format:
in hexadecimal form for an MBR disk or as a GUID for a GPT disk.

So obviously, the last answer does not work.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).